# Node JS - Backspace not working in Node-Pty Terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, terminal, pty

I have this simple code

```js
const os = require('os')
const pty = require('node-pty')
const process = require('process')
const { msleep } = require('sleep');
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require('fs');
const { exit } = require('process');

const usage = `Usage: term-record [OPTION]

OPTION:
  play [Filename]        Play a recorded .json file
  record [Filename]      Record your terminal session to a .json file`

var shell = os.platform() === 'win32' ? 'powershell.exe' : 'bash'
var lastRecordTimestamp = null
var recording = []
var args = process.argv
args.splice(0, 2)

function getDuration() {
    var now = new Date().getMilliseconds()
    var duration = now - lastRecordTimestamp
    lastRecordTimestamp = new Date().getMilliseconds()
    return duration
}

function play(filename) {
    try {
        var data = readFileSync(filename, { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r'})
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code == 'ENOENT') {
            console.error("Error: File Not Found!")
            exit(1)
        } else {
            console.error(err)
            exit(1)
        }
    }

    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data)     
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error: Invalid File!");
        exit(1)
    }

    console.log("------------ STARTING ------------");
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        process.stdout.write(data[i].content);
        msleep(data[i].delay)
    }
    console.log("-------------- END ---------------");
}

function record(filename) {
    var ptyProcess = pty.spawn(shell, [], {
        name: 'TermRecord Session',
        cols: process.stdout.columns,
        rows: process.stdout.rows,
        cwd: process.env.HOME,
        env: process.env
    });

    process.stdout.setDefaultEncoding('utf8');
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8')
    process.stdin.setRawMode(true)
    process.stdin.resume();

    ptyProcess.on('data', function(data) {
        process.stdout.write(data)
        var duration = getDuration();

        if (duration < 5) {
            duration = 100
        }

        recording.push({
            delay: Math.abs(duration),
            content: data
        });
    });

    ptyProcess.on('exit', () => {
        process.stdin.setRawMode(false);
        process.stdin.pause()

        recording[0].delay = 1000
        try {
            writeFileSync(filename, JSON.stringify(recording, null, '\t')); // JSON.stringify(recording, null, '\t') For Tabs
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })

    var onInput = ptyProcess.write.bind(ptyProcess)
    process.stdin.on('data', onInput)
}

if (args.length === 2) {
    var file = args[1]
    if (args[0] == "record") {
        console.info("Setting App Mode to 'Record'")
        console.info("Setting Output file To '" + file + "'")
        record(file)
    }
    if (args[0] == "play") {
        console.info("Setting App Mode to 'Play'")
        console.info("Setting Input file To '" + file + "'")
        play(file)
    }
} else {
    console.log(usage);
}
```

The `record` function takes a argument `filename` and then starts a new terminal using node-pty module, and when `on data` event occurs it simply calculates the the milliseconds from the last time this `on data` event triggered, and pushes a object into `recording` array, and this object has two properties, 1st is delay, and second is the text. and when the `on exit` event triggers, it simply closes the terminal and saves the `recording` array to a json file with name equal to the variable `filename`

The `play` function takes a argument `filename` and then reads the data from the file and parses it to a JavaScript Array which contains multiple objects, and if something goes wrong it throws an error. after parsing it simply uses a for loop to iterate over the array and writes the data to the console and waits for some milliseconds.

Problem is, when I record my session, and when i press `Backspace` key to remove a character, then it weirdly puts a space between it, like shown below:

[image: Sorry for the fps]

In the gif, after I ran the first command and typed out `ls -ls` then i pressed <kbd>Backspace</kbd> 2 Times, which resulted a weird blank space 2 times.
and after i pressed enter it showed a error `ls: cannot access '-': No such file or directory` which meant the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key removed 2 characters from the input but and it executed `ls -` instead of `ls -ls` but for some reason those 2 characters were not removed from the console when i pressed <kbd>Backspace</kbd> twice instead it added a weird blank space

How do i fix this issue?

This is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "term-record",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Simple Terminal Session Recorder",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
  "author": "ADITYA MISHRA",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-pty": "^0.10.1",
    "sleep": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```

- My NodeJS version: v16.11.1
- My NPM version: 8.1.2
- My Linux Distro: Arch Linux with XFCE 4

I tried switching to nodejs version 14.18.1-1, but that didn't help too

Comment: can you please be more precise please describe at which line you see an additional space from the gif video it looks fine

Comment: I use ubuntu, could not reproduce this in ubuntu, it could be keyboard mapping problem in arch. Can use run this `setxkbmap -model evdev -layout us -variant colemak` to change keyboard layout.

Comment: MANNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN!!!!!!!! Actually Your answer didn't work exactly because it literally change my whole keyboard layout but when i ran `setxkbmap -layout us` it just works now!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i had my keyboard layout poorly selected, which caused the backspace key to add a space.

I ran the following command `setxkbmap -layout us`, to change my keyboard layout to US and now it works